# Laravel on Nginx serving a blank page

Tags: php, nginx

So, I've been busting my head these last two days trying to install Laravel. I'm new to this framework, but wanted to learn it. I installed it using composer on our Nginx server. After that I changed the Nginx config file. Now, all I'm getting is a blank page and nothing else. I also changed `app/storage`'s permissions.

Below you can find my config file:

```
server {
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    root /var/www/website.com/htdocs/public/;

    index index.php index.html;

    #browse folders if no index file
     autoindex on; 

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # enforce NO www
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }


    # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
    # if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/lobby(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # catch all
    error_page 404 /index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        #include fastcgi_params;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Check your permissions for `www-data` user

   ```
   sudo chown -R :www-data /your/location
   ```
2. Check your document root path
3. Check this section again: `location ~ \.php$`...

   ```
   location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
   ```
4. Check error logs
5. Uncomment & modify `;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` to `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` in `php.ini`
6. Use Homestead & Forge

Comment: Nope, There's something else to it which i'm trying to figure out too.

Comment: Something else like what exactly. Maybe I can help. I've done this quite a lot